# Magic Fields 2 custom post type disappeared?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

Anyone run into this issue? You can see the highlighted post type 'Learning Civilization,' but it seems to have disappeared from the magic fields menu... I've uninstalled and reinstalled the plugin thinking it was a glitch, but the settings remain the same—very odd.

See image here: http://qikr.co/tqbxs